# how to fix this huge mistake I ran sudo chown -R user /

Tags: permissions, mount, sudo, chown

How can I fix this issue?
the user is not the root one
and unfortunately one of the mounted disks that got affected too was the apps disk of my windows but I am not sure if it got affected as I can still run those apps and open stuff there
is it possible to fix the linux now? or will I have to reinstall?

I ran

```
sudo chown -R non-root /
```

Comment: Reinstalling your system is the fastest solution.  (However, this exact question has been asked NUMEROUS times and this is a duplicate of those)